# Silverlight 4. Need same instance in multiple groups

Tags: silverlight, datagrid

I want to display a class presenting a worker who have different skills.

The datagrid must be able to group by Skills

So worker 1 have skills C# and Java
Worker 2 have skills SQL and C#

My grid should display the following

C#

- Worker 1
- Worker2

Java

- Worker 1

SQL

- Worker 2

(The sort order is not relevant)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use LINQ to group them how you want:

```
var WorkersGroupedBySkills = 
    Workers
        .SelectMany(w => w.Skills)
        .Distinct()
        .Select(s=>new{Skill=s,Workers=Workers.Where(w=>w.Skills.Contains(s))});
```

Then create the UI to display the higherachy using an Items Control with a data template which contains and expander and within the expander, a grid to show the workers with those skills.
Alternatively there are a number of third party grids with grouping capabilities which may be able to handle the new data model.